# Tiff: adding a new page with no re-encoding

Tags: c#, .net, image

I have a JPEG file taken from database and i need to add it as a new page to existing or new multipage TIFF file encoded as JPEG. Is there .NET library which is able to add a page with no re-encoding? I need to process a lot of images quickly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what i was looking for: [BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.WriteRawStrip](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/tiff.writerawstrip2.aspx)